# Product of the reaction of ethyl acetoacetate with alkaline benzoyl chloride followed by addition of ammonium chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

> What does this β-keto ester give when reacted with $\ce{PhCOCl/NaOH}$ followed by $\ce{NH4Cl(aq)}?$
>
> [image: ethyl 3‐oxobutanoate]

According to me, the $\ce{PhCOCl}$ should react with $\ce{NaOH}$ forming benzoic acid which should attack the ester on the right, forming an anhydride and a ketone.

Also, whats the function of $\ce{NH4Cl(aq)}$? Is it a proton donor?

Comment: Beta-ketoesters are carbanion sources and would undergo nucleophilic acyl substitution with $\ce{PhCOCl}$.

Comment: The intent of the question is to make the anion of AAE and then benzoylate the anion. But is it C or O benzoylation? The NH4Cl is added to neutralize any bases.

Comment: @shreya $\ce{NH4Cl}$ is used to [quench the reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work-up_(chemistry)#:~:text=quenching%20a%20reaction%20to%20deactivate,by%20filtration%2C%20decantation%2C%20or%20centrifugation) (neutralize any leftover base)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, $\ce{NH4Cl}$ is used as a proton donor where you don't want anything else in your reaction flask to be affected by the $\ce{H^+}$ conc. in the medium

Comment: Reagents should be added in an order here: $$\ce{SM ->[1. NaOH][2. PhCOCl] P} \\ $$ You cannot add $\ce{PhCOCl/NaOH}$ together because they react with each other as noted.

Comment: See: Org. Synth. 1938, 18, 33; DOI: 10.15227/orgsyn.018.0033 for the synthesis of ethyl benzoyl acetate. Notice that ammonia and NH4Cl is used to cleave the acyl group.